# create sum of cell matrices

Tags: matlab, octave, cells

I want to have the sum of all matrices stored in a cell array. Currently I do this

```
StackSummImage = zeros(size(imageList{1}));
for k = 1:stackSize
     StackSummImage = StackSummImage + imageList{k};
end
```

But I would rather want to write it in a single line if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If each of the N images is K x K, you can use `cat` to concatenate all the images into a K x K x N array, and then sum it along the third dimension:

```
>> imageList = {[1 2; 3 4], [5 6; 7 8], [9 10; 11 12]};
>> stackSummImage = sum(cat(3,imageList{:}),3)
ans =
15    18
21    24
```

**Edit:** You mentioned in the comments that you can't create a single array, because of memory limits. Below is the memory usage profile when I first allocate a 1500x1500x1500 array of doubles (which takes around 30 GB) and deallocate it, followed by allocating a cell array of 1500 arrays, each of which is a 1500x1500 double array. As you can see, the total memory usage is the same in both cases.

[image]

Comment: I can not create such an array. I save the data in a cell array because the whole data is 4-10 GB.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech Why do you think in a cell array it takes less space?

Comment: Because cells are pointers to arrays and a single 3D array is a single block in memory. I can load all data with cells, but could not if I tried to allocate a single 3D array.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech Do you mean that you have enough memory to store that data in a cell array, but not enough memory to create a copy?

Answer (score -1):

This line should do:

```
StackSummImage = sum([imageList{:}])
```

Comment: This will result in a vector, not an array of the same dimensions as the original images.